# Complex meaning of separable verbs in German

Tags: meaning, verb, separable-verb

I'm just starting out with German, and this may sound dumb, but here it goes. So, here is a sentence:

> Kann ich meinen Hund mitnehmen?

This translates to

> Can I take my dog with me?

in English. The thing that I don't quite get is why there is no word denoting "me". Is it baked into the separable verb "mitnehmen"? If so, then is it common with separable verbs in German to have things like indirect objects being included in their meaning?

Comment: Advice: Never assume that for every word in one language there is a corresponding word in the other language. Another example: *I am going to drive home* is not *Ich bin vorhabend Hause zu fahren* but *Ich habe vor, nach Hause zu fahren*. In turn *Ich habe vor, nach Hause zu fahren* is not *I have before to drive to home* but *I am going to drive home*. You see, English and German typically use different expressions to represent the same matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, *mitnehmen* has no built-in “me”.

> Kannst du deinen Hund mitnehmen? — Can you take your dog with you?

The English phrasal verb is *to take something with someone* and it needs to tell that person who takes the direct object. And that must be a backreference to the subject but puzzingly, not with a reflexive pronoun. It's a complicated verb phrase.

German *mitnehmen* is much simpler. Such an non-reflexive reflexive adverbial is not needed at all. The subject suffices. You *can* however add the adverbial.

> Kann ich meinen Hund **mit mir** mitnehmen?

> Kannst du deinen Hund **mit dir** mitnehmen?

It's allowed but not too common. If you add that adverbial, it emphasizes the action. Unlike in English, it's truly reflexive.

> Kann er seinen Hund **mit sich** mitnehmen?

*Sich* is the only reflexive pronoun German has. Otherwise we use the personal pronouns.

Comment: "deinen Hund" = "your dog" oder "meinen Hund" = "my dog"? Bin nicht sicher, was im Beispiel gemeint ist ...

Comment: Es geht nicht um den Hund. Der ist doch nur das Akkusativ-Objekt bzw. Direct Object. Es geht um das Adverbial. Im Englischen ist das zwar auch reflexiv, denn es **muss** auf das Subjekt verweisen. Allerdings seltsamerweise nicht mit Reflexivpronomen, sondern mit Personalpronomen.

Comment: Ich weiß, aber im ersten Beispiel sieht es so aus, als wäre "my dog" die Übersetzung für "deinen Hund".

Comment: Oh, hab's nicht gesehen. Danke.

Comment: English has particle verbs while German has separable verbs, but my impression there are many more of the latter. So it's not surprising that there are separable verbs with no corresponding particle verbs and "mitnehmen" is an example.  I would say that German has many reflexive pronouns, but most of them look just like the corresponding personal pronouns. That's just a terminology choice though.

Comment: Thank you for noting that "sich" is the only reflexive one. People often misunderstand this.

Comment: @RDBury: a German base verb has typically ten to twenty prefixed variants. There are only a very few verbs with less than ten prefixed variants. Also, those prefixed variants may be particle verbs as well.

Comment: @Janka - I don't know if the ratio is that high, but it's pretty high. For example, "take" has one particle variant I could find -- "take off. (There are many other phrasal verbs though. including prepositional verbs.) German has "abnehmen", "annehmen", "aufnehmen", etc. The comparison gets a bit strained when you get into the details, for example "aufnehmen" = "pick up", which is a particle verb but the base verb is not "take".

Comment: FYI, *aufpicken* exists in German as well but it means a different thing. I have the impression that English lumps more meanings together into one verb.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no baked in *me* or *you* or any other pronoun in the verb *mitnehmen.* What really puzzles you and many other English native speakers is the meaning of the prefix *mit-* in many German words like *Mitglied, Mitarbeiter, mitmachen, mitnehmen, mitbringen, mitwirken, mitarbeiten, mitspielen, Mitbürger, mitreißend* and many more.

This prefix *mit-* is closely related to the preposition *mit* which is *with* in English, but when used as prefix, is better translated as *co-.* This prefix that you find in many English words is derived from the latin word *cum* which means *with, together, in combination:*

- The **Mitarbeiter** is literally a **co-worker** (a *with-worker*), i.e. someone who works with others. But more frequent English terms are *employee, member of staff* or other words that start with *co-* or *con-:*

  - *contributor* (latin cum = with, latin tribuere = to allot, to pay)
  - *collaborator* (latin cum = with, latin laborare = to work)
  - *colleague* (latin cum = with, PIE<sup>1</sup> leg = to collect, to gather)
- The verb **mitarbeiten** is closely related to the noun *Mitarbeiter* and means to **co-work** (to work in a team or as a member of a group).
- The word **Mitglied**, which is *member* in English is built from *mit-* and the noun *Glied.* Later can mean a limb (*arm, leg,* but also *penis*), but also a *link* (in a chain) or in a mathematical context a *term* in a sequence or series or more general a *constituent* (latin cum = with, latin statuere = to set, to stand, to make firm). So, the literal meaning of *Mitglied* is like *co-link* or *co-constituent* which already has a doubled *co-* in it.
- A **Mitbürger** is literally a *co-citizen,* i.e. a citizen among other citizens. So you maybe should think of *Mitbürger* as *fellow citizen,* but in most situations just *citizen* (German: Bürger) will do it as well.
- The verb **mitmachen** means *to participate,* but is built from *mit-* and *machen* (to do, to make) and therefore literally means **co-do** or **co-make,** i.e. you do or make something together with others.
- When you hear the verb **mitbringen,** you should interpret is as **co-bring.** You bring something as a side-effect of being there anyway. I have written more about the difference between *bringen* and *mitbringen* in [another answer](https://(latin%20cum%20=%20with,%20PIE%3Csup%3E1%3C/sup%3E%20leg%20=%20to%20collect,%20to%20gather)).
- The verb **mitnehmen** is very similar to *mitbringen* and can be interpreted as to **co-take.** What I've written about *mitbringen* in the linked answer is also valid for *mitnehmen.*

I could continue this list for dozens or maybe even hundreds of German words that all start with *mit-* and I always would stress out that you should try to find an English word that starts with *co-.* Even if that constructed word in most cases is not a real English word (like *co-citizen* or *co-bring*), it maybe helps you to get the correct menaing of the German word.

---

So, here is your sentence:

> Kann ich meinen Hund mitnehmen?

First, let's think about a plausible context and the meaning of this sentence: A person who says this sentence just was invited to join some activity (to go for a walk with someone, to visit a friend, etc.). The invited person has a dog and they want that their dog also is allowed to join the same activity. So, the dog accompanies the invited person, i.e. the dog does something *aside* to its owner, or *as companion* of its owner. So the dog's activity is a *co-*activity. And the meaning of the German sentence is this:

> Can I let my dog join our planned activity?

So, the focus is not at bringing the dog with me, but on having the dog as member of our group. So you don't ask *"Can I bring my dog with me?"«* but you ask *»"Can I let my dog join us?"«*

---

<sup>1</sup> PIE = Proto-Indo-European

Comment: "... dozens or maybe even hundreds of German words that all start with mit- ...": DWDS lists a total of 52 under its two entries for "mit". Many of the "co-" words come to English through Old French instead of directly from Latin, and meanings may drift in the process. A random example: "Mitleid" = "compassion", but breaking down "Mitleid: produces "co-sorrow". "Passion" as "suffering" is obsolete in English except in certain phrases.